# Print Result of a form on the same page with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, web

i have this code for registration :

a. controller

```html
<?php  
 class Manual extends CI_Controller {  
      public function __construct(){  
           parent::__construct();  
           $this->load->model("model_manual");  
      }       
      public function index(){  
      $this->insert();       
      }  
      public function insert()  
      {  
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama', 'Nama', 'required');  
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('npm', 'Npm', 'required');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('matkul','Matkul','required');  
           if ($this->form_validation->run())  
           {       
           $register=$this->model_manual->insertdata($_POST);  
           if($register){  
                     echo "<script>alert('Input Sucessfully')</script>";  
      }  
           }  
           $data['title']="Input data";  
  $data=array('isi'   =>'home/manual_view');
  $this->load->view('layout/wrapper',$data);       
      }  
 }  
 ?>
```

b. model

```html
<?php  
 class Model_manual extends CI_Model {  
  function insertdata($options = array()){  
           if(isset($options['nama']))  
                $this->db->set('nama',strip_tags($options['nama']));  
           if(isset($options['npm']))  
                $this->db->set('npm',strip_tags($options['npm']));   
           if(isset($options['matkul']))  
                $this->db->set('matkul',($options['matkul']));  
                $this->db->insert("tabel_manual");  
           return $this->db->insert_id();  
  }  
   
  function cek_user($data) {
   $query = $this->db->get_where('tabel_manual', $data);
   return $query;
  }
  
  function getAllUser() {
  $this->db->from('tabel_manual');
  return $this->db->get();
  }
  
 }  
 ?>
```

c. view

```html
<div class = "well" style = "background-color :lavender;">

<button class="btn btn-default" style= "padding-top : 9px; padding-bottom : 9px;"><a href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home" style = "text-decoration : none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></button>
<button class="btn btn-default"><a href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>blanko" style = "text-decoration : none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Blanko</a></button>

<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6" style = "text-align : center">
<label style = "font-size: 20px;">INPUT DATA</label>
</div>

<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" style = "margin : 10px;">
  
  <div class="form-group">
  <label style = "font-family : cambria;">Nomor Pokok Mahasiswa :</label>
  <input style = "font-family : cambria;" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder = "Typehere"
  name="npm" id="npm"/>
  <font color="#FF0000"><?php echo form_error('npm');?></font>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
  <label style = "font-family : cambria;">Nama Lengkap :</label>
  <input style = "font-family : cambria;" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder = "Typehere"
  name="nama" id="nama"/>
  <font color="#FF0000"><?php echo form_error('nama');?></font>
  </div>
    
  <div class="form-group"> 
  <label style = "font-family : cambria;">Mata Ujian :</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="matkul" id="matkul">
  <option value="">Select</option> 
  <option value="pancasila">Pancasila</option>  
  <option value="matdas2">Matematika Dasar 2</option>
  <option value="ap2">Algo.Pemograman 2</option>
  <option value="ap3">Algo.Pemograman 3</option>
  <option value="matif4">Matematika Informatika 4</option>
  <option value="sisber">Sistem Berkas</option>
  <option value="arkom">Arsitektur Komputer</option>
  <option value="jarkom">Jaringan Komputer</option>
  <option value="si">Sistem Informasi</option>
  <option value="so">Sistem Operasi</option>
  <option value="imk">IMK</option>
  <option value="sbd2">SBD 2</option>
  <option value="tbo">TBO</option>
  <option value="rpl2">RPL 2</option>
  </select> 
  <font color="#FF0000"><?php echo form_error('matkul');?></font>
  </div>
  
  <br>
  <div class="form-group"> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style = "font-family : cambria; ">Input</a></button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" style = "font-family : cambria;">Reset</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </form>
 
 </div>
 </div>
```

for the view, i use bootstrap to make design of my interface. 
the question is... how can i print the result from the form went i "click" the submit button in the same page?

i just want to make form, and after that below that form, i can showing the result.

Answer (score -1):

@ariyanti you have to use session when you submit your form then at insertion time you need to set session of form data and then you can  print your form post data using session and i have a simple way for form submitting as compared to your code in codeigniter if you are agree then i will help you..

Comment: you want some help ??